# ES6 Class Definition, methods and function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm new to ES6 and try to migrate old javascript code.
Now my class use methods but is not clear why not all methods are attachetd to 'this'.
Is not even clear if i can use methods as function (and pass as callback)

```
class MyClass{
    construtor (parameters)
    {
        this.myInternalState = new ExternalClass ( this.method1CallBack );
        this.varClass1 
        this.varClass2...
    }

    method1CallBack (){} //OK attached to this
    method2 (parameter){} //KO not found in this object
}
```

Is not clear where is my mistake, in code syntax or in the interpretation of the method's use.

Comment: `KO not found in this object` what? 3

Comment: debbuging the code i was not able to find 'method2' in the 'this' inside 'method1CallBack '.
But more i debug and more i suspect that the problem is in the caller.
Are there any issue with the scope if the caller is not ES6?

Comment: You have to bind the callback to `this`. Like so: `new ExternalClass(this.method1CallBack.bind(this))`

Comment: @Skary This has nothing to do with ES6. `this` works just like it always did for methods.